# VSCode freezing upon startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode is freezing upon starting in CentOS 7 (Linux smcr-centos7-x64-vm0 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64) when I install/use any version newer than 1.52. It comes up but I can't click anything in the window and it practically cripples my VM. I also don't see anything in the launch window. Here's the output of "code --list-extensions":

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:2073)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at bindings (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/spdlog/index.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1155:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:823:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at t (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:101)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:1719)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10262)
    at l (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10314)
    at Object.errorback (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10435)
    at r.triggerErrorback (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10626)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10332
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:1736)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10262)
    at l (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10314)
    at r._loadModule (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:10444)
    at r._resolve (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:6:452)
    at r.defineModule (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:6145)
    at r._relativeRequire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:6831)
    at n (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:9420)
    at y (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:14:20443)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at b (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:14:20423)
    at L._createSpdLogLogger (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:14:21356)
    at new L (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:14:21172)
    at P.initServices (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:17:45235)
    at async P.run (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:17:44511)
    at async Object.D [as main] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cliProcessMain.js:17:48104)
    at async E (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/cli.js:12:14219) {
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'spdlog',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous5===' ]
}
aaron-bond.better-comments
albert.TabOut
alefragnani.project-manager
arturock.gitstash
bradgashler.htmltagwrap
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
eamodio.gitlens
ecmel.vscode-spring-boot
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.auto-close-tag
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
humao.rest-client
jebbs.plantuml
kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks
mads-hartmann.bash-ide-vscode
mongodb.mongodb-vscode
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-python.python
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-vscode.cpptools
oderwat.indent-rainbow
philsinatra.nested-comments
Pivotal.vscode-boot-dev-pack
Pivotal.vscode-concourse
Pivotal.vscode-manifest-yaml
Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot
purplestone.savebackup
redhat.java
redhat.vscode-commons
redhat.vscode-xml
redhat.vscode-yaml
rogalmic.bash-debug
shakram02.bash-beautify
stkb.rewrap
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
TomiTurtiainen.rf-intellisense
trixnz.go-to-method
vilicvane.sensitive-replace
vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven
vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard
vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr
vscodevim.vim
wix.glean
wmaurer.change-case
xaver.clang-format
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
```

Comment: Any help from https://www.programmersought.com/article/43396308266/

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123374

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Debian 12 (xfce). It kept freezing even with --disable-gpu, while --verbose wasn't showing anything useful: VS Code starts and gets frozen immediately. For an experiment, I installed code-insiders package, which didn't have the issue. Surprisingly, after this, the original VS Code also started working, and it works even after VS Code Insiders is uninstalled. Sounds like a possible workaround.